# Dual screen with two ATI cards

Tags: 11.04, ati, multiple-monitors, xinerama

I'm trying to get a dual screen setup he main monitor in landscape and the other on portrait.
With the ATI binary drivers (CCC) I could have both monitors working although I couldn't activate Xinerama because ubuntu won't even load the GUI.
Using the open source drivers I don't know where to activate my second card to the second monitor.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 with two video cards each card has connected one monitor.

Here is my lspci:

```
elio@main:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon HD 5870 (Cypress) [1002:6898]
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon HD 5870 (Cypress) [1002:6898]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Until the compiz xinerama bug is solved, select classic ubuntu (no effects) on logon to make xinerama work.